# Unable to download STS Windows x64 version

Tags: download, spring-tool-suite, sts, spring-tools-4

I'm trying to download the STS 4.11.0 at the official Spring website for 2 last days but getting this error:

> --2021-07-22 17:50:09--  (try:20)  https://download.springsource.com/release/STS4/4.11.0.RELEASE/dist/e4.20/spring-tool-suite-4-4.11.0.RELEASE-e4.20.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar
> Connecting to download.springsource.com (download.springsource.com)|104.26.13.6|:443... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
> Giving up.

Comment: I double checked the download URL and that seems to be correct - and working on my end. Maybe a company proxy server in between that causes issues while transferring the data?

Comment: Thank You Martin. I've tried to download in Internet Explorer and have success now. But in Google Chrome and in WGET still getting error.